# Regex remove all numerics and dots with empty strings

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following:

WRONG

> Address 1: 12 ST. JOHN DRIVE
>
> Address 2:

CORRECT

> SAON: 12
>
> Thorofare: ST JOHN DRIVE

I need to perform some REGEX to match these two addresses, as you can see the main differences between them are:

1.) The road name has been written in the house name/number field

2.) There is a DOT after the word ST in the wrong address.

I have a list of CORRECT addresses which match the WRONG address in question's postcode. From this list I want to filter it down to the correct 1 address.

This is what I have so far:

```
Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.paon.Trim() == Regex.Replace(exception.AddressLineOne, "[^0-9.]", "") && x.thorofare.Trim() == Regex.Replace(exception.AddressLineOne, "[^\\d-]", ""));
```

What I'm trying to do is firstly remove everything that is not a number from the WRONG address 1 and match it with the CORRECT `saon`, then remove everything that is a number from the WRONG address 1 and also, whilst I'm at it replace any

> .

with an empty string, and then match that with the CORRECT `thorofare`.

I think I have done the first part in my code, but cant see how to also remove the dot and replace it with an empty string?

So, how do I, using regex, remove all numeric's from `exception.AddressLineOne` and also replace the dots with nothing?

Comment: are you familiar with the `string.Replace` Function..?

Comment: Yes, can you show me how I might use it to accomplish what I want?

Comment: you will want to look up string.Contains function as well and you can also write your own logic using the char.IsDigit function..

Comment: Replace `/[0-9\.]/g` with `""`.

Comment: So regex is not the way to do this?

Comment: @Shellfish I get unrecognized escape sequence with your suggestion

Comment: I don't know the `c#` regex syntax, my apologies. Try one of the following: `/\[0-9\.\]/g/`, `/[0-9.]/g/` or `/\[0-9.\]/g/`. Maybe the *global modifier*, `g` should be placed elsewhere in `c#` or you may don't need leading and trailing slash symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.paon.Trim() == Regex.Replace(exception.AddressLineOne, "[^0-9]", "") && x.thorofare.Trim() == (Regex.Replace(exception.AddressLineOne, "[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "").Trim()))
```